# Weird output when trying to insert element to array column of a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to insert 0 at the beginning of the array column of this pyspark dataframe.

[image]

This is the way I did it

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
udf_addEle = F.udf(lambda x: [0]+(x), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

labs.select(udf_addEle(F.col('glu_agg'))).show()
```

However when I run it, I am getting this weird output. Cannot figure out why. Could anyone please help. What should I do to avoid this error? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Works for me. I get the expected output

Comment: Got the answer.. It was the ArrayType(IntegerType()) which was causing the problem.. changed it to ArrayType(FloatType()) - solved the problem..

Comment: @pissall Isn't it worth mentioning that this should be done without a `udf`, which in this case has two disadvantages - it breaks the on type mismatch and is never going to be as optimised as combination of `concat` and `array` functions?

Comment: @napoleon_borntoparty The mentioned solution is something that didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @napolean_borntoparty's comment, here is a more optimal solution:

```
df = df.withColumn("new_glu_agg", F.concat(F.array(F.lit(0)), F.col("glu_agg")))
```

You can use `concat` to combine two arrays. I created one array of `0` as the only element and concatenated it with the existing `glu_agg` column.